# R tools for visual studio 2013

Tags: c#, r, visual-studio, r.net

I am currently using Visual Studio 2013. I want to integrate my .net application with R by using R.net. But the websites are showing that R Tools needs Visual studio 2015 or a higher version. Is it possible to do it by using Visual studio 2013? If anybody knows the link to the installation process, please help me out by sharing it.

Comment: Have you *tried* using your version of VS2013 with RTools?

Comment: Hi, I was able to install the Rtool of version 1.6.5 with my VS2013. Can anyone please tell me where to find a good tutorial on how to proceed with this now? I want to learn R.net.

Comment: Have you *tried* looking at the documentation?  It's not that complicated: http://jmp75.github.io/rdotnet/

Comment: Hi I am able to use RTools in VS2013.